# Building a Search Procedure - MySQL - LIKE with multiple values vs LIKE with Temp Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am sure that this question has been asked in many ways but I could not find an answer that comprehensively laid out my specific scenario - so here goes.

I am building a search function across multiple tables and fields. There is one table to store person information, another table to store their address information and yet another table to store their telephone information.

The screen provides a keyword input - which will trigger the search. The user can input a single keyword or multiple comma separated keywords

As I evaluated various options here is what I came up with

1. Do the search within a stored procedure since the search query will run against multiple different tables and different fields - this complete SQL logic is better kept in the database layer.
2. Send the keyword(s) as a comma separated or pipe separated string to the stored procedure from PHP - therefore, all the pre-processing of the keywords is done in PHP
3. Have the stored procedure process the search query and return a combined resultset that can be readily displayed

I have multiple options to design the stored procedure and this is where I am looking for advise / input from the community

After much reading on the use of LIKE vs REGEXP, I settled on the use of `LIKE` option to match keyword(s) against various attributes in the database and then generate a `UNION` of resultsets against various tables to send back

Pros - `LIKE` is extremely fast. It is very simple to use and gets the job done

Cons - If the user enters multiple keywords, then the logic gets very complicated as I have to generate multiple `OR LIKE %keyword%` statements within the stored procedure. An alternate option could be to use temporary tables and insert the results of each keyword search into the same

Question - does the use of temporary tables slow down performance of a stored procedure significantly? Average number of rows to be matched against will range around 8000 to 10000 and max limit could be 100000.

So will there be significant degradation in performance if I use a `WHILE` loop to search each keyword against the tables and insert results into a temporary table as opposed to dynamically generating `OR LIKE` statements and running a single query.

Comment: LIKE is not always fast as a matter of fact LIKE can really slow things down. WHen using a like statement with a wildcard in front i.e. `LIKE '%someterm%'` MySQL cannot use indexes and thus will do table scans. As soon as you start scaling you will slow down tremendously. Do not use LIKE unless you absolutely have to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, I have decided to go ahead with inserts into a temporary table instead multiple `LIKE` statements because of the following reasons

1. Over complication of the query statement - multiple `LIKE` clauses just created a very complicated stored procedure design and resulting query
2. Individual queries will probably be just as efficient as one large complicated query - even if there is a trade off I suspect it will be minor. I havent tested this with live data yet but will post an update once I have sufficient volume